# Full dark-mode in Microsoft Word (2016): dark page background

Tags: microsoft-word, colors, dark-mode

With dark theme mode in Windows 10 the Office Word background stays white.

Without changing the color of the text background in a Word document while writing and reading there is no "dark mode" feel as the white background fills the view.

[image]

I am looking for some time for this feature that is available in LibreOffice under Tools-Options-Application colors

[image]

I am posting this in order to provide the answer.

Comment: This is available to those on the "Insider Channel" in Word 365. I do not know that it will ever be available directly in Word 2016. Should be in Word 2021.

Comment: You may want to adjust your display's brightness. Your eyes shouldn't hurt when viewing brightly-colored content with proper settings.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon - I have tested this in Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016. I see [here](https://www.bates.edu/helpdesk/2018/05/04/microsoft-office-page-background-color-in-word-it-training-tip/) a post that says it should work in 2011, 2013 and 2016 versions of Word. I guess 2019 too.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon - [new answer on 365](https://superuser.com/a/1663795/1039759).

Comment: It now is working on the regular (non-insider) monthly channel of Word 365.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATED ANSWER:

Simply go to "View" and select

[image]

---

Old answer:

[{Source}](https://ktconnections.com/blog/tip-of-the-week-how-to-switch-microsoft-word-to-dark-mode)

Under "Design", select "Page color":

[image]

Your document will preview the colors as you hover over the options under "Theme colors".

[image]

For example:

[image]

---

As for the risk of **having the dark background printed** – as suggested in comment - that doesn't happen in Office Word 2016, because the specific option (*File > More... > Options > Display > Print background colors and images*) is **disabled by default**.

[image]

[image]

[image]

*I can confirm this for Office Word 2016, but cannot guarantee for older versions. Therefore, in such cases one should check that the aforementioned option is disabled and even do some testing - and post back here for all to know.*

For more options on that, see [this post](https://www.bates.edu/helpdesk/2018/05/04/microsoft-office-page-background-color-in-word-it-training-tip/), which says that this is also available for Office 2013 and 2011.

It also points out that:

- *The page background color will not be printed, but will be saved as part of the document.*
- *When changing your page background color, it will only be applied to that specific document and is not a global or default change.*
- *You may want to change the page background color to No Color when saving a document that is shared with other individuals or when sharing the document electronically*.

Comment: Unless you are not printing backgrounds in Word, this will print this way.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon - `unless you are not printing backgrounds [...] this will print [backgrounds]`: of course either X or non-X is true, but in this case (Word 2016) one of the terms (printing backgrounds) is disabled by default.

Answer (score 2):

**For those using version 2106 of Word 365 (not sure about Word 2016 or 2019)**

If you go to File -> Options -> General, there is an option on the "Personalize your copy of Microsoft Office" section and select Black theme, the page background is black. There is a "Disable dark mode" setting next to the theme. When it is not selected, the page has a black background while using the Black theme.

[image: Disable dark mode setting]

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple: go to the design and click to change the background to black.
See the screenshot: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiRbr.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).